# <input value={{:abc}} /> does not seem to work properly in jsviews if the value of 'abc' has whitespace

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

I'm using jsviews to render the following template

```
recoList = [{title:"Apple"},{title:"Two Apples"}];

<script id="sampleTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
{{for recoList}}
  <input type="text" value={{:title}} />
{{/for}}
</script>
```

Whenever the value of title has a whitespace in it, like "Two Apples", then input box is rendered as

```
<input type="text" value="Two" />
```

The word after the whitespace is simply spliced off!

How can i give the full string to the value?

Comment: I managed to get this to work by adding a data-link instead of value={{:title}}. Like this :  
                                                                     <input type="text" data-link="title" />

Comment: Have you tried quoting it? `value="{{:title}}"`

Comment: Quotes don't work either.....the data-link works fine for now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `data-link` instead of `value={{:title}}` solves the problem for now.

Like so :

```
<input type="text" data-link="title" />
```

However, i still don't know why `value={{:title}}` splices the string after whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple. You are missing the quotes:

`<input type="text" value={{:title}} />`

should be:

`<input type="text" value="{{:title}}" />`

JsRender simply replaces the tag by the value, so:

`<input type="text" value=Two Apples />`

should be:

`<input type="text" value="Two Apples" />`

You says quotes don't work, but the above should certainly work. Using `data-link="title"` will add the quotes, but also adds data binding, so you get two-way binding to the title field...