# Jsrender data value break on whitespace

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender, jsviews

i am using jsrender and i got issue on accessing value

```
{{for items}}
  <input type="text" id="id1" value="{{*: Json.stringify(data)}}" />
{{/for}}
```

here i got value as: "{" id":"1","name":"johnny depp"}"

$("#id1").val() gives **'{'** all other values trimmed and

```
<input type="text" id="id1" value={{*: Json.stringify(data)}} />
```

here i get: "{id":"1","name":"johnny" depp"}

$("#id1").val() gives '{id":"1","name":"johnny'

the words after the space is getting trimmed how can i show full value

i have tried the solution as in [<input value={{:abc}} /> does not seem to work properly in jsviews if the value of 'abc' has whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404778/input-value-abc-does-not-seem-to-work-properly-in-jsviews-if-the-value/21424180#21424180) but still not working

Comment: issue is with double quotes i have tried with custom function so when ever doubles quotes passed only values inside first starting and closing quotes is taken all other will be ommited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the string returned from `stringify()` includes double quotes `"`, you need to instead use single quotes `'` for the `value='...'` on the markup for the input:

```
<input type="text" id="id1" value='{{*: JSON.stringify(data)}}' />
```

which will give

```
<input type="text" id="id1" value='{"id":"1","name":"johnny depp"}' />
```

Now `$("#id1").val()` will give: `'{"id":"1","name":"johnny depp"}'`